# Kubernetes a job is moved to another pod

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

A long running job (45h) is moved to another pod causing it to restart.

From the logs I can see that the job received a SIGTERM then it was restarted on another pod and probably on another node too.

The informations retrieved in google cloud are not helping. The pages `Yaml` or `events` do not describe this event except for the pod creation.

The job Yaml `creationTimestamp: 2019-06-15T10:39:25Z`

The pod Yaml `creationTimestamp: 2019-06-17T13:26:25Z`

I use mostly a default configuration `1.12.6-gke.11` with several of nodes and the servers are not preemptible.

Is it a default behavior of k8s ? If it is, how can I disable it ?

Comment: Are you using cluster autoscaling? Does the pod request adequate resources - i.e. was it evicted (showing status "Evicted"), or simply moved because of an issue with its node? Do you have node automatic upgrades enabled? Do you have a PodDisruptionBudget for the pod?

Comment: We are using `autoscaling`. There was no status `evicted`, if it was a node problem we didn't see it in GCC. We have `automatic upgrade` enabled and the pod has no `PodDisruptionBudget`.
This is a recurring problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've said that you're using cluster autoscaling, I'm going to assume that the pod is getting removed because the cluster is getting scaled in. We saw a similar issue because we're running video transcoding jobs using a 0-scaled node pool (which then scales out as jobs are added).

Looking into it, we found the [autoscaler documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#what-types-of-pods-can-prevent-ca-from-removing-a-node) about the autoscaler and then modified our jobs accordingly:

> What types of pods can prevent CA from removing a node?
>
> - Pods with restrictive PodDisruptionBudget.
> - Kube-system pods that:
> - - are not run on the node by default, *
> - - don't have a pod disruption budget set or their PDB is too restrictive (since CA 0.6).
>
> Pods that are not backed by a controller object (so not created by deployment, replica set, job, stateful set etc). *
>
> Pods with local storage. *
>
> Pods that cannot be moved elsewhere due to various constraints (lack of resources, non-matching node selectors or affinity, matching anti-affinity, etc)
>
> Pods that have the following annotation set:
>   `"cluster-autoscaler.kubernetes.io/safe-to-evict": "false"`

It was the last one that did the trick for us. I recommend using this as a starting point.

Comment: Ok thanks, We'll try that and come back with results (this might takes some days)

Comment: @should OK :) I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes the annotation fixed the problem. Thanks